# protobuf installed but cannot be imported in Poetry environment

Tags: python-packaging, python-poetry, protobuf-python, mlrun

I created a Poetry environment with following toml file:

```
[tool.poetry]
...

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
mlrun = "1.4.1"
pyyaml = {file = "PyYAML-5.4.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl"}


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Everything is installed successfully, however, MLRun cannot be imported due to Protobuf: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.protobuf.pyext._message'`. When importing Protobuf alone, it also gives error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'protobuf'`. I know a workaround is to `import google.protobuf`, however, this is not possible for me as the import is part of the MLRun package. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Some clues? https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amlrun%2Fmlrun+protobuf&type=code -- I guess I would try putting a version constraint on protobuf: `protobuf<4`.